# How can I use primefaces datatable?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have class Task and class File which have `List<Task> tasks` as attribute.
How can I display details of tasks in datatable which contains details of file?

```
<p:dataTable var="files" value="#{fileMB.files}" id="file" >

                <p:column style="width:35px">
                    <p:rowToggler />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="FileName" style="text-align: center;"
                    sortBy="#{files.fileName}" filterBy="#{files.fileName}">

                            <h:outputText value="#{files.fileName}" />

                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="TaskName" style="text-align: center;">

                            <h:outputText value="#{file.tasks.taskName}" />

                </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

An Error Occurred:For input string: "taskName"

Comment: Welcome to SO. I would like to close this question because it is seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. So, please improve your question.

Comment: Please attach the bean, the entities and the proper error message.

Comment: you can use a rowExpansion

Comment: pb resolved : I use "get":                                                                       
 <p:column headerText="TaskName" style="text-align: center;"><h:outputText value="${files.tasks.get(0).taskName}"/>            
</p:column>

Answer (score 0):

pb resolved : I use "get":

```
 <p:column headerText="TaskName" style="text-align: center;">
        <h:outputText value="${files.tasks.get(0).taskName}"/> 
 </p:column>
```

Comment: Those are the details of 1 task!!!, And `${files.tasks[0].taskName}` works to. And your naming of 'files' is kind of strange, shouldn't it be 'file' since you iterate over files, you get a file...